# Underscore, can't call replace of undefined

Tags: backbone.js

I've experienced this error before and tried the solutions I've found on SO for it, but I can't get around it in this case by trying the solutions I've found.  I have a question_template that I placed in the header of my index file with the js script tags at the bottom of the file. In the initializer to the view, I get the template using jQuery html function, and the console log shows the template is retrieved from the index.html. However, when i try to insert it into underscore _.template, it's triggering the can't call replace of undefined error

```
 var QuestionView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $(".east"), 
initialize: function(){


    var template = $('#question_template').html();
    console.log(template);
    this.template = _.template(template);   #error triggered


},
```

Since I'm able to log the template, I don't see what my problem is? This is part of the underscore code.

```
text.replace(matcher, function(match, escape, interpolate, evaluate, offset) {
source += text.slice(index, offset)
.replace(escaper, function(match) { return '\\' + escapes[match]; });
```

First question: What would 'text' represent, which, in my case, is undefined? I would have thought that 'text' is the template, but since I can log my template how is it undefined?

I also have all of the js code (including the initialization of the Question view) wrapped in the document ready, which in other SO questions on this issue was the solution

```
$(function() {


  ...code ommitted...
  var question_view   = new QuestionView({ model: game});



});
```

Second question: is there anything else I can try

**Update**
Note, I subsequently pass the model data to the template but it never gets that far because the error is triggered

```
**$(this.el).html(this.template(response));**
```

I prepare the templates in three steps

```
1. var template = $('#question_template').html();
        console.log(template);
2.      this.template = _.template(template);

3. $(this.el).html(this.template(response));
```

Comment: sorry, I took out the 'this' if that was the problem (I had been playing around trying to figure out what the problem was). It doesn't work either way. The code pattern is one I got from another backbone app that works. Isn't it right to pass the local variable 'template' into _.template(template)

Comment: yes, I think so, how else can I log the template before the line of code that triggers the error?

Comment: Since the error is in the template function, the problem is probably the template you are passing it.  Post the template.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke you were right. I found it, voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the model data to the template,

this.template = _.template(template, this.model.toJSON());

Comment: sorry, see the update. I do eventually pass the model data to the template, but it never gets that far because the error's triggered. I prepare the template in 3 steps. First, var template = $('#question_template').html();  Second.  this.template = _.template(template); Third, $(this.el).html(this.template(response));   but I'm never getting to the third step